# How can I separate txt and pdf from unpack content file processor in Apache-NiFi, and leave in Queue?

Tags: apache-nifi

I was trying to unzip a file (which contain 2 file format, one PDF and another txt). I was able to unzip it, now needs to separate it and keep it in 2 separate queues, one will hold txt and another will do PDF. If anyone can assist me how to approach this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `RouteOnAttribute` processor.

add 2 properties into it:

```js
match_txt = ${filename:toLower():endsWith('.txt')}
match_pdf = ${filename:toLower():endsWith('.pdf')}
```

as result this processor will have 2 output relations: `match_txt` and `match_pdf`

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.